# Fixed number of digits for size regardless of case/unit

Tags: python, math

I have the following code:

```
def format_sizeof(num, suffix='', divisor=1000):
    """
    Formats a number (greater than unity) with SI Order of Magnitude
    prefixes.
    Parameters
    ----------
    num  : float
        Number ( >= 1) to format.
    suffix  : str, optional
        Post-postfix [default: ''].
    divisor  : float, optional
        Divisor between prefixes [default: 1000].
    Returns
    -------
    out  : str
        Number with Order of Magnitude SI unit postfix.
    """
    for unit in ['', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z']:
        if abs(num) < 999.5:
            if abs(num) < 99.95:
                if abs(num) < 9.995:
                    return '{0:1.2f}'.format(num) + unit + suffix
                return '{0:2.1f}'.format(num) + unit + suffix
            return '{0:3.0f}'.format(num) + unit + suffix
        num /= divisor
    return '{0:3.1f}Y'.format(num) + suffix
```

What I am looking to do is to adapt it so that it always prints the same number of digits, regardless of the case/unit, while still maintaining human readability.

This is to ensure that the same width is printed every time the terminal flushes.

I came across several approaches, padding, string typecasting, math.log10.

I am not sure what is the best way to exactly go about solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation on string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

> *width* is a decimal integer defining the minimum total field width,
> including any prefixes, separators, and other formatting characters.
> If not specified, then the field width will be determined by the
> content.
>
> The *precision* is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be
> displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted
> with `'f'` and `'F'`, or before and after the decimal point for a floating
> point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`. For non-number types the field
> indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters
> will be used from the field content. The *precision* is not allowed for
> integer values.

In other words, for a floating-point with `'g'`, *width* gives the minimum number of characters, including digits and decimal point, and *precision* gives the maximum number of digits.

The *width* is the number before the dot in the format string. The *precision* is the number after the dot in the format string.

Here is an example with a *precision* of 5 (maximum 5 digits), and a *width* of 6 (minimum 5 digits + 1 decimal point):

```
>>> '{:6.5g}'.format(123.4567)
'123.46'
>>> '{:6.5g}'.format(12.34567)
'12.346'
>>> '{:6.5g}'.format(12.1)
'  12.1'
>>> '{:6.5g}'.format(12.0)
'    12'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print a number using `n` digits (and you're sure you don't need more than `n`):

```
from math import log10

x = 42
n = 5
print(format(x, f'{n}.{n-1-int(log10(x))}f'))
```

Result:

```
42.000
```

`log10` is separate from the other math functions, so fairly optimised, although since you're only interested in the integer part of it, you might be able to get a bit faster still.